# Checking for errors and exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

The Account class is to have each method that throws a clause check for an error and throw the appropriate exception, how would I do this? When trying to compile the AccountApplet class for both if statements i get error: unreported exception EmptyFieldException; must be caught or declared to be thrown so I am assuming the error is that i have not finished the Account class as per my first question

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;  

public class Account
{
  int id         = 1234;
  double balance = 1000.00;

  Account (int id, double balance)
  {
    id      = 1234;
    balance = 1000.00;
  }

  public int getId()
  {

    return id; 
  }

  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;   
  }

  public void setBalance(double balance) throws NegativeAmountException
  {

    // check for error and throw exception

  }

  public void deposit(double amount) throws NegativeAmountException
  {
    // check for error and throw exception
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount) throws NegativeAmountException,
                                             InsufficientFundsException
  {
    // check for error and throw exception
  }
```

AccountApplet class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;


public class AccountApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{    
  //  For West
  public JLabel  ai       = new JLabel("Account ID ");
  public JTextField  aitf = new JTextField();
  public JLabel  ab       = new JLabel("Account Balance ");
  public JTextField  abtf = new JTextField();

  //  For East
  public JButton     dp   = new JButton ("Deposit");
  public JTextField  dptf = new JTextField();
  public JButton       wt = new JButton ("Withdraw");
  public JTextField  wttf = new JTextField();

  // For South
  public JLabel  status   = new JLabel("placeholder");  


  public void init()
  {
    this.setSize(400, 90);

    //----------------------
    //  Set up the Structure
    //----------------------

    Container      c = getContentPane();
    JPanel         b = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel      west = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
    JPanel      east = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel depo_with = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));



    // Add BorderLayout to the container
    c.add(b);

    // Add everything to West
    b.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);


    west.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Display Account Information"));
    west.add(ai);
    west.add(aitf);
    aitf.setEditable(false);
    west.add(ab);
    west.add(abtf);
    abtf.setEditable(false);

    // Add everything to EAST
    b.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);

    east.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Deposit or Withdrawl Funds"));

    east.add(depo_with, BorderLayout.EAST);

    depo_with.add(dptf);
    depo_with.add(dp);
    depo_with.add(wttf);
    depo_with.add(wt);

    dp.addActionListener(this);
    wt.addActionListener(this);

    // Add everything to SOUTH
    b.add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    refreshFields();






  }  // End intit

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

    if (e.getSource() == dp)  //  Executes if deposit was clicked
    {
      //getAmount(dptf);
      status.setText("Deposit processed");

      refreshFields();

    }    

    if (e.getSource() == wt)  //  Executes if withdraw was clicked
    {
      //getAmount(wttf);
      status.setText("Withdraw processed");

      refreshFields();
    }
  }  // End actionPerformed

  public void refreshFields()
  {
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    Account Account1 = new Account(1234, 1000.00);
    aitf.setText("" + Account1.getId());
    abtf.setText("" + fmt.format(Account1.getBalance()));
    // diplays accound id and balance in left text fields
    //should be called when the applet is first displayed and after each valid transaction
  }

 public double getAmount(JTextField tf) throws EmptyFieldException,
                                             NumberFormatException,
                                             NegativeAmountException
{
    double withdraw;
    // try to parse 
    try 
    {
        withdraw = Double.parseDouble(dptf.getText());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // catch exception and do something about it  
        throw e;
    }
    // Next step

    return withdraw;
}  //  End    
} // End Class
```

EmptyFieldException

```
public class EmptyFieldException extends Exception

{
  EmptyFieldException() 
  {
    super();

  }
```

InsufficientFundsException

```
public class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception
{
  InsufficientFundsException()
  {
    super();
  }

}
```

NegativeAmountException

```
public class NegativeAmountException extends Exception
{
  NegativeAmountException()
  {
    super();
  }
}
```

Comment: [Just throw it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html).

Comment: @Compass how would this one work I keep on getting an unreachable statement error?   public void withdraw(double amount) throws NegativeAmountException,
                                             InsufficientFundsException
  {
    if ( amount < 0)
    {
      throw new NegativeAmountException();
      throw new InsufficientFundsException();
    }
  }

Comment: Throwing an exception is the end of the method. It's like a return statement, any code after the return statement cannot be executed. Only way to get around that is to use a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

I guess some part of the code is missing or not complete. In your code there is just one method("getAmount(JTextField tf)") where you are throwing EmptyFieldException. Hence wherever you are calling this method, you need to have either a try-catch block surrounding that or need to throw exception at the method level. I could find the reference in couple of places in AccountApplet class, but they are commented. Something is missing :|

Comment: I know you don't have enough reputation, but this should be a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), not an answer.

Comment: Thank Mifeet, Sorry this is my first post in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In your AccountApplet class you commented out the `getAmount(wttf)` method - I guess the error pops up when you uncomment it.

Since this method throws several Exceptions, you must either declare them to be thrown by your `actionPerformed` method aswell (Would not recommend this, since this is an event) or catch it and handle the error:

```
if (e.getSource() == dp)  //  Executes if deposit was clicked
{
  try {
     getAmount(wttf);
     status.setText("Deposit processed");

     refreshFields();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     // Something went wrong - handle your error here
     status.setText("Error occured");
  }

}    

if (e.getSource() == wt)  //  Executes if withdraw was clicked
{
  try {
     getAmount(wttf);
     status.setText("Withdraw processed");

     refreshFields();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     // Something went wrong - handle your error here
     status.setText("Error occured");
  }
}
```

Comment: How would i declare it to be thrown and not have the try catch blocks? in the actionPerformed method it only checks which button was selected and the status is updated depending on the error. The getAmount method reads the amount in from one of the JTextFields and converts it to a number. The getAmount method also catches the NumberFormatException, the catch block then throws the exception to the method that calls it.